# VBA Sorting function Between Two Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function to copy values in one table on an excel sheet to corresponding values onto another table on a separate sheet. This is the code I have written so far, however it only sorts certain values and leaves the rest blank. Would anyone know how I can improve this?

```
Sub ctppll()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    
    For i = 2 To 50
        For j = 2 To 500
            If Worksheets("X").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("DIRECTORY").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
               For k = 3 To 9 Step 1
                   Worksheets("X").Cells(i, k).Value = Worksheets("DIRECTORY").Cells(j, k).Value
               Next k
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

`"X"` is the sheet I am trying to sort the values into and `"DIRECTORY"` is the sheet (essentially a bank of values) that the function is sorting from.

Comment: To clarify: Are the values in column 1 of the DIRECTORY-sheet in the same order as the values in column 1 of  the X-sheet, or are they jumbled?

Comment: Have you tried the new XLOOKUP function, which can return several cells, eg in columns, if it finds a match? No need for VBA.

Comment: Xlookup, Vlookup, Index-Match and ... You are comparing DIRECTORY sheet values with values in Column A of X sheet and if matched at first instance then you are populating K column in X sheet. Therefore, if values are not match the remaining cell will be empty. Simply you can copy Col A of X sheet to Col K of X sheet and use any of the abovementioned functions. No need for VBA :)

Comment: To clarify, the values in column 1 of the DIRECTORY sheet are out of order from column 1 of the X-sheet. In addition, I am trying to keep the cell format the same from the X sheet as it is on the DIRECTORY sheet.